# What happens if I point dropbox to existing but old folder?

Tags: sync, dropbox

Assume I have Dropbox installed on a computer A.

1. I make a backup of computer A disk.
2. I add/change/delete some files on A and sync.
3. Later I load the backup on another computer B, install (clean, no previous installation data) dropbox and point it to the old dropbox folder.

The questions:

1. Will dropbox on computer B reupload files which were deleted at the step 3?
2. Will dropbox on computer B delete files which were added at the step 3?
3. Will it cause conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New install means Dropbox is going to compare the file hash of every file in the Dropbox with what's in the cloud.

So, yes, no, yes.

If there is a file hash difference, Dropbox will append the file with ([Machine Name Conflicted Copy Date](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/36)) and give you two copies of the file to figure out.

You're better off having Computer A and Computer B on the same subnet, configure LAN sync, and let Dropbox perform the sync utilizing LAN sync speeds. The scenario you describe ends up being a pain because you end up with files you don't want and conflicted copies.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an exact duplicate however I do think this is your solution.

[How does Dropbox determine when to overwrite the local file vs overwrite the cloud file?](https://superuser.com/questions/690963/how-does-dropbox-determine-when-to-overwrite-the-local-file-vs-overwrite-the-clo)